How can change PRODUCT_NAME to a language other than English in xcode?
I'm making a macOS program.
I'm trying to change the launcher icon name to Korean.
So I went into BuildSetting and changed the Product Name to Korean, but the build failed.
BundleDisplayName and BundleName couldn't change the icon name.
I've been wasting my time for days. ㅠㅠ
I'm tryed change 'BundleDisplayName' and 'BundleName'. But not worked.
Changed 'Target Runner' name. and when I tried to build, it failed because it couldn't load the packages.
